# Game force closes after phone call? - Android

Tags: android

I have a game in Android that force closes after resuming from a phone call.
I'm guessing I've not implemented som method correctly and I'm guessing it has something to do with savedInstanceState.

If I should save the state with savedInstanceState what should be stored there, every object and position of that object?

Or is there something very vital I'm missing?

Comment: show the stacktrace please and onResume() code.

Comment: This might be a stupid question but I've never tried to stacktrace before. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out and it was not related to saveInstance at all.

My Gamethread was messed up and needed to create a new thread in in the surfaceCreated method.

Like this:

```
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                _thread = new GameThread(getHolder(), this);
                _thread.setRunning(true);
                _thread.start();
    }
```